# 2 Lists - Linking together, having trouble

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, lookup-column, calculated-column-formula, share

Company description - Widget Rental Services

2 Lists -

List 1 = Customer Order/Scheduler (Non Calendar)
List 2 = Inventory/Asset List

When inputting customer order on list one, we would like to book an asset.  We need to pull available asset from List 2.  When asset is booked or rented out, we need it to show dates next to asset when pulling up asset availability in Customer Order (list 1).

We are stuck and can not get it figured out.  I understand this question is most likely confusing.  I am available for a direct message or call if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a **many-to-many** relationship and you need three lists:

1. Customers
2. Assets
3. AssetReservation

**AssetReservation** will have two lookup columns, one pointing to Customers and the other to Assets. It will have [Booking] or [Reservation] date plus any other columns as needed by the business requirements.

**Customers** list (simplified): LastName and FirstName *Single Line* and FullName *Calculated* column with formula `=LastName&", "&FirstName` .
Make *Title* column not required.

**Assets** list: Rename *Title* to AssetName, Add *AssetDescription* as *Single Line* column, and Add *TotalQuantity* as a Number column

**AssetReservation** List: *Title* column may not required and can be set optional. Add *ReservationDate* as a Date column. For lookup columns, refer to the screenshots below.

### Customer Lookup column

[image]

### Asset Lookup column

[image]

### Data Entry form for AssetReservation

[image]

[image]

[image]